Does the twin paradox hold in a universe that's empty except for the twins?
I recently obtained a used copy of Shadowitz's obscure book on Special Relativity, in which he makes the following astounding claim (which I have not seen elsewhere) concerning the twin paradox with twins A and B:

In a universe consisting only of A and B, with no other matter present, the twin paradox would no longer exist: the twins would be identical and interchangeable. There would then be only the symmetrical time dilation effect; there  would be no asymmetrical twin paradox. In such a universe there would be no distinction between Galilean and non Galilean observers.

(Shadowitz makes this comment after mentioning a paper by Feenberg called "The Doppler Effect and Time Dilation".)
This seems like a sort of Mach's principle for linear acceleration, and the only way I can make sense of it is to note that it might be impossible for an observer A to accelerate independently of B without ejecting matter, therefore negating the premise that A and B are the only matter in the universe.
Is Shadowitz mistaken?

If the "twins" are actually point particles with no internal structure, and there is nothing else in the universe, then the twin paradox might be inconclusive -- but in this case the twins themselves can make no observations and have no opinions, nor can they possibly turn around, so the situation just cannot arise.
If the twins are more like actual people flying in rocket ships, then they can easily distinguish the inertial from the non-inertial twin -- the non-inertial twin will feel acceleration when the rocket turns around.
This is going by mainstream physics, of course. Some non-mainstream theories may invoke Mach's principle to suggest that neither twin could "feel" acceleration were it not for the influence of the rest of the universe. These theories have no actual evidence to support them, whereas the mainstream ones have accumulated a considerable body of supporting evidence.

I would hardly call Mach’s principle a “theory”. Theories have mathematical frameworks; I have never once seen a consistent piece of math relating to Mach’s principle. I agree with everything except that piece of wording, +1

Ah, it's the infamous spherical twins!

How do you distinguish whether the one who feels the acceleration from turning around, did in fact turn around, and it's not just the other twin also starting to accelerate?

@kutschkem the reason you can physically feel acceleration is that parts of your body are trying to continue to move in a straight line at constant speed. So if you feel acceleration you're not moving steadily. Another way to think of it is that each twin could release a ball outside their spaceship. The one who turns around will move away from their ball. The twin who is "stationary" will remain next to their ball.

@EricSmith Maybe I am thinking about this wrong, but I imagine an empty universe with two observers moving away from each other (one is moving, one is stationary; as far as I understand, you can't tell which one is which). One starts accelerating towards the other. How can one tell whether it was the moving, or the stationary observer that is accelerating? In both cases the acceleration would be felt.

@kutschkem Speed is relative, so "moving" and "stationary" are in general arbitrary labels. But the feeling of acceleration is not relative. The twin who feels acceleration is the one who turns around and ages less. There are 3 inertial reference frames in the twin paradox: that of the non-accelerating twin, the outbound frame of the twin who turns around, and the inbound frame of that twin. No matter which frame you consider to be "stationary" the calculation comes out the same: the twin who turns around ages less.

According to both special and general relativity, the amount of proper time between given events is path-dependent.
If one invokes a hypothetical universe with only two things in it then there are two possibilities:

the hypothetical universe is described by physical laws such as special and general relativity

the hypothetical universe is not described by physical laws like those


It appears that Shadowitz is committing a contradiction, for he is trying to suppose a hypothetical universe which is claimed to be like ours, but which is not described by physical laws like special and general relativity. On this basis I conclude that Shadowitz is wrong on this point. The mistake might come from thinking that Mach's principle is compatible with general relativity, but it is not.

Short answer: it is inconclusive. Now the long answer.
The questions

Does the twin paradox hold in a universe that's empty except for the twins?

and later

Is Shadowitz mistaken?

are sort of opinion-based. The fact is that the universe is not empty except for the twins, and the scenario Shadowitz describes does not exist. It is unachievable. We have no way of knowing. Shadowitz seems to believe Mach's principle would apply exactly and hence there is no paradox.
To get out of the realm of speculation, we can choose a theory and ask what it says with regards to your question. You tagged the post with "special relativity", so I assume you are interested in the point of view of special relativity. In special relativity, the twin paradox does occur because one of the twins is not inertial, and this breaks the symmetry. Mach's principle is not part of special relativity and in this case, the twins would measure different times.
A much more complicated question is what general relativity would say. In this case, I don't think there is an objective answer without further information. What you would have to do to answer it is:

Have a precise model of what the twins are made of. Point particles are particularly problematic in general relativity (a massive point particle would form a black hole and you have issues with radiation reaction), so you need a field theory, and everything gets complicated. Suppose you somehow had a matter model for them.
Knowing the matter model, you have the differential equations (the Einstein equations), but you still got to solve them. This means you need an initial condition. The location and momentum of the twins is not sufficient. You need to solve for the geometry of the universe, so you need to tell how all the universe looks like. Is it a sphere? A plane? A hyperboloid? Something different? Each of these cases would lead to a different geometry and could lead to a different answer. For example, the twin paradox in Minkowski spacetime is very different from the twin paradox in a universe with one compact dimension. Schwarzschild spacetime is a vacuum solution (so there is no additional matter in the spacetime), does this still count as an empty universe or is the black hole a problem?

Due to these nuances, I don't think the question admits a straightforward answer. "A universe that's empty except for the twins" does not specify the spacetime in a sufficiently unique way for relativity to give an answer (it may depend on your model, initial conditions of the whole universe, etc), and if you are going beyond relativity (or a previously chosen gravitational theory) this is fully opinion-based.

Meta comment: I think the title question "Does the twin paradox hold in a universe that's empty except for the twins?" may be opinion-based (I've seen similar Mach's principle questions closed for similar reasons), but I think "Shadowitz statement is opinion-based" is not opinion-based. I think the question is on-topic, but I see reason for other people to disagree

Note that OP also mentioned he's referring to a SR book. This one I believe. So in this sense I think the theory (and metric) were already "chosen" for us here, and the first part of your answer could suffice, (without suggesting that I object to the additional interesting remarks about GR, it's nice to provide a wider view!).

Do any explanations of the twin paradox ever use anything but SR and Minkowski spacetime? Why is it necessary to bring Mach's principle into it?

@D.Halsey Well, either Shadowitz is invoking Mach's principle, or it's impossible in this scenario for A or B to have a bent / kinked worldline because they can't eject matter, as mentioned by the OP.

But is there any geometry (i.e., background vacuum solution of Einstein eqns) where there is "no asymmetrical twin paradox" or "no distinction between Galilean and non Galilean observers"? I dodn't have any context from the book, but it seems to me you're giving the author a lot of credit for a statement that on the face of it looks silly (i.e., a simple application of Mach's principle).

@Toffomat Any Lorentzian geometry distinguishes between geodesic curves and non-geodesic curves, and I'm pretty sure that all geometries admit both geodesic and non-geodesic curves (hence, it is always possible to distinguish both cases). However, there is a difficulty: in this scenario, you can't make a point-particle approximation and the observers need to be treated as extended bodies. This could make the physics way more complicated than a mere question of Galilean vs non-Galilean observers

Exactly. But of course, the problem with point particles applies in GR even for Minkowski backgrounds, so it's not going to turn the original point of the book into a correct one

@Toffomat I agree partially. The problem technically is there, but in our universe the point particle approximation works. In the imaginary universe of the author, the approximation may break down earlier (although I wouldn't expect it to lead to the author's conclusion)

And it's hard to see why it should break down if and only if the universe is empty except for the twins.

Of course it does. SR does not depend on the contents of the universe, only the motion of the 2 twins.
